# How to set default image of type : 'thumbnail' and URL:'https://blalblabla'?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

How can I set default image of type: 'thumbnail' and URL:'https://blalblabla' ? 
Can I make with mongoose-scheme? More details?

```
const Images = new Schema({
kind: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['thumbnail', 'detail'],
        required: false
    },
    url: {
        type: String
    },
});

const Tags = new Schema({
    label: {
        type: String
    },
});

const ArticleScheme = new Schema({
    images: [Images],
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    author: {type: String, required: true},
    text: {type: String, required: true},
    views: {
        type: Number,
        default: 123
    },
    tags: [Tags],
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You just add property default

```
kind: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['thumbnail', 'detail'],
    default: 'thumbnail'
}
```

You don't need `required: false` in this case.